# I am getting a permission error with tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract

Hello I have this code and getting this error: PermissionError: [WinError 5]

```
 import pytesseract
    import os
    import shutil
    
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="C:\\Users\\ekrem\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR"
    directory='C:\\Users\\ekrem\\Desktop\\resimler'
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        b=os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if 'CRN' in pytesseract.image_to_string(b):
            print(b)
            a=pytesseract.image_to_string(b).index('CRN')
            print(pytesseract.image_to_string(b)[a-6:a-1])
        else:
            destination='C:\\Users\\ekrem\\Desktop\\fails'
            c = os.path.join(destination, filename)
            shutil.copyfile(b,c)
```

Here is the error message I added it:

```
C:\Users\ekrem\Desktop\Projects\distribution>python distribution.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distribution.py", line 9, in <module>
    if 'CRN' in pytesseract.image_to_string(b):
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 370, in image_to_string

    return {
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 250, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Erişim engellendi
```

[image]

Here is my path

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the entire error traceback message.

Comment: Run your script as admin or add your `tesseract` to your PATH. then there is no need to use `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd`.

Comment: I edited my path, it is wrong. Because I am getting still the same error

Comment: The image you post is no the `path`, it is `TESSDATA_PREFIX`.

Comment: how should I add tesseract to my path

Comment: The same as how to add python to your path.